# R error using weights in ENmisc's wtd.boxplot

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use the wtd.boxplot function in the package ENmisc and having an issue with getting the weighting to work - example as follows:

```
# make some dummy data
A <- as.data.frame(seq(20,50,1))
A$Grp <- 'A'
A$Wt <- 1
names(A) <- c('Val','Grp','Wt')

B <- as.data.frame(seq(1,30,1))
B$Grp <- 'B'
B$Wt <- 1.2
names(B) <- c('Val','Grp','Wt')

C <-  as.data.frame(c(seq(40,80,5))) 
C$Grp <- 'C'
C$Wt <- 1.4
names(C) <- c('Val','Grp','Wt')

dt <- rbind(A,B)
dt <- rbind(dt,C)
dt$Grp <- as.factor(dt$Grp)
```

If I use no weighing the plot works fine:

```
#load weighted boxplot package

require(ENmisc)

# boxplot with no weights

wtd.boxplot(dt$Val ~ dt$Grp,
            weights = NULL
            )
```

but when I specify the weighting column as follows:

```
# boxplot specifying weights column

wtd.boxplot(dt$Val ~ dt$Grp,
            weights = dt$Wt
            )
```

I get an crytpic error message as follows:

```
Error in if (any(out[nna])) stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(x[!out], na.rm = TRUE) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: I think the problem arises from having no variability in your values within groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your example so that there is variablity within groups, there is no error. Appears the author of this package did not trap that error and report an information error or insert a workaround:

```
A <- as.data.frame(seq(20,50,1))
A$Grp <- 'A'
A$Wt <- runif(31)
names(A) <- c('Val','Grp','Wt')

B <- as.data.frame(seq(1,30,1))
B$Grp <- 'B'
B$Wt <- runif(30)+2
names(B) <- c('Val','Grp','Wt')

C <-  as.data.frame(c(seq(40,80,5))) 
C$Grp <- 'C'
C$Wt <- runif(9)+5
names(C) <- c('Val','Grp','Wt')

dt <- rbind(A,B)
dt <- rbind(dt,C)
dt$Grp <- as.factor(dt$Grp)
require(ENmisc)
wtd.boxplot(dt$Val ~ dt$Grp,
            weights = dt$Wt
            )   # no error
```

After looking first at `traceback()` and then at the code for `wtd.boxplot` and then the code for `wtd.boxplot.stats`, I used `options(error=recover)` and `str(stats)` to find this:

```
Browse[1]> str(stats)
 num [1:5] 40 52.5 67.5 NA NA
```